# Using Material UI with Storybook (and makeStyles)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, storybook

I'm trying to use Storybook with MUI components, and they work well until I have to pass a prop to them since I'm using the makeStyles hook.

`Styles.js`

```js
export const headerStyles = makeStyles({
  title: {
    fontFamily: 'DM Sans',
    padding: 50,
    fontWeight: 500,
    fontSize: 28,
  },
  header: {
    background: '#4F36D6',
  },
});
```

`Header.js`

```js
export default function Header() {
  const { header, title } = headerStyles();
  return (
    <AppBar className={header} position="static">
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography className={title}>UI Styles - Aula en casa</Typography>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

and this would be what I was trying to do without much success

`Header.stories.js`

```js
export default {
  title: 'Header',
  component: Header,
};

export const Primary = () => {
  const { header } = headerStyles();

  return <Header className={header}></Header>;
};
```

is it possible to use the makeStyles props inside the story?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What is happening that you are not having success?

Comment: @SethLutske it doesn't crash, but the header shows without the style on the title that should be applied with `headerStyles()`

Comment: `makeStyles` returns a react hook, so it is suggested to name it appropriately, i.e. something more along the lines of `useHeaderStyles`. The `Header` component uses the hook internally and also doesn't consume any props, so passing a `className` prop to it from the story will have no effect. Your stories can be functional components, so they can also use react hooks. Have you inspected the DOM to see if your styles are injected into it? Are the styles overridden?

Comment: @DrewReese inspecting the DOM doesn't seem of much use here, but the styles don't seem to be overridden. Btw, I don't know if it's related, but the font source I'm using comes from google fonts installed using a `<Link />` inside the `<Body />` of `index.html`, instead of one that comes from MUI